# ButtonGroup null pointer exception

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I've created a method that will clear any previous selections made to my ButtonGroup that is comprised of radio buttons

```
    public void resetRadioButtons() {

    if (group.getSelection() != null) {
        group.clearSelection();
    }
    else {

    }

}
```

The group is instantiated here:

```
        final ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(radioAnswer1);
        group.add(radioAnswer2);
        group.add(radioAnswer3);
        group.add(radioAnswer4);
```

When the method is called it gives a NullPointerException at the line:

```
if (group.getSelection() != null) {
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide full code to look into it.From the exception it is clear that group reference is pointing to a null object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite possibly youre [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `group` variable. Try replacing

```
final ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
```

with

```
group = new ButtonGroup();
```

Comment: Oh sweet, that worked :D Thanks a bunch. Just out of curiosity, what does the "final ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();" mean?

Comment: it means you're creating a variable whose reference cannot be changed. In your case it looks as though you're doing this in a method or constructor (which isnt setting another variable of the same name at class level)

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is indeed on this line

`if (group.getSelection() != null) {`

(and not in `getSelection()` itself),
then `group` is `null` there.

Make sure it's initialized first.